# iphone: Core Data: NSManagedObjects and UITableView crash

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data, nsmanagedobject

This fetch method work perfectly and the NSLog prints out the contents of the database...(fetchedObjects in an NSArray):

```
NSError *error2;
fetchedObjects = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error2];

if (!fetchedObjects) {
    NSLog(@"Error %@",[error2 localizedDescription]);
}

for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects) {

    NSLog(@"Name: %@", [info valueForKey:@"Name"]);
    NSLog(@"Description: %@", [info valueForKey:@"Description"]);
    NSLog(@"Ingredients: %@", [info valueForKey:@"Ingredients"]);
```

.. but when I try to populate a tableView (I have built many tables and feel i have a good understanding of how they work), the program crashes with a "EXE_BAD_ACCESS at int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);."  That is it, no other error messages.

To try and debug, I put this simple NSLog in the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method, but it crashes at NSLog(@"fetchedObjects count in tableview %i",[fetchedObjects count]).

I haven't released the array as far as I can tell.

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    NSLog(@"fetchedObjects count in tableview %i",[fetchedObjects count]);
    NSManagedObject *info3 = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", [info3 valueForKey:@"Name"]);
    cell.textLabel.text = [info3 valueForKey:@"Name"];
```

Comment: What is the number of rows count in your numberOfRowsInSection? in which method you are initializing the fetchedObjects?

Comment: Hi Praveen.  I use `return [ArrayNameHere count];`   Currently it is 27.  Which means the array is there...!?!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `fetchedObjects` instance variable is being deallocated because of an autorelease pool flush.

`NSManagedObjectContext`'s `-executeFetchRequest:error:` method returns an ***autoreleased*** `NSArray` instance, which you aren't obtaining ownership of, therefore by the time execution reaches the `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, the autorelease pool has been flushed, and that object is deallocated, and you now have a dangling pointer. Ah, classic.

The solution, of course, is to send the `-retain` message to the returned `NSArray` from sending `-executeFetchRequest:error:` to your `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Don't forget to send the `-release` message to it in your `-dealloc` method.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. I copied fetchObjects into another array: `displayArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:fetchedObjects];` and printed out the contents (everything is ok).  I check the array just before calling the table reloaddata [displayArray count], which works just great too.  Changed tableView to point at this new array and it still crashes on the NSLog ` NSLog(@"displayArray count in tableview %i",[displayArray count]);` I even created another array manually and pointed the tableView at that to be sure table was working (and it is).  I also cleaned the project several times just in case.

Comment: Got it working at last.  I should have copied `fetchedObjects` into a new array so: `displayArray = [fetchedObjects mutableCopy];`  Would seem copying array using `[NSArray arrayWithArray:fetchedObjects]` wasn't correct.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jeremy Creating a copy is way more expensive than simply calling `-retain`. You should really do what I told you and not make a copy. It's unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be on this line

NSManagedObject *info3 = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Try to use

NSManagedObject *info3 = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];

Because your UiTableViewCell count and  fetchedObjects count should be equal at whole process.

If it doesn't match then it will give you index error.